# jQuery alerts is not working on jquery 1.11.2 , "TypeError: n.browser is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I use to work well with jQuery alerts inside jQuery 1.8.2 , from :-

> / jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin // // Version 1.1 // // Cory S.N.
>   LaViska // A Beautiful Site (http://abeautifulsite.net/)

but now i have upgraded to jQuery 1.11.2 , and i start receiving this error when calling jAlert :-

```
TypeError: n.browser is undefined


...er").addClass(n.alerts.dialogClass);var e=n.browser.msie&&parseInt(n.browser.ver...
```

now i checked the related scripts and i found that it use $browser which is no more available inside jQuery 1.9 :-

```
_show: function(title, msg, value, type, callback) {

            $.alerts._hide();
            $.alerts._overlay('show');

            $("BODY").append(
              '<div id="popup_container">' +
                '<h1 id="popup_title"></h1>' +
                '<div id="popup_content">' +
                  '<div id="popup_message"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>');

            if( $.alerts.dialogClass ) $("#popup_container").addClass($.alerts.dialogClass);

            // IE6 Fix
            var pos = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed'; 

            $("#popup_container").css({
                position: pos,
                zIndex: 99999,
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0
            });
```

so can anyone adivce on this please? not sure if i can upgrade my jAlert to a newer version that works on jquery 1.9 + ?

Comment: You should probably upgrade to jAlert v2.

Comment: can you please mention the url  to download version 2?

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction (with the emphasis on jerk), is to ask you if you've heard of Google, but I'll spare you that and point you to http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/

Comment: @j08691 if only people realized how easy it is to dump a code error into a search box and typically get immediate results

Comment: so the newer version comes with two scripts ; jAlert-v2-min & jAlert-FB . should i include both of them?

Answer (score 0):

> $.browser Will not work in jQuery 1.9 or later unless the [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin is included.

Source: `http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/`

Comment: i do not want to add any migration scripts, so i either upgrade the current jAlert or to look for another package..